# TSQL Find Missing Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables:

TableA is a calendar of all possible weeks we should have sales data for per company.

TableB has financial data for sales per company per week that have been reported.

TableA Columns

```
[cmp_code, Year, Week]
```

TAbleB Columns

```
[cmp_code, Year, Week, sales]
```

**Query Criteria:**

1) List weeks missing from TableB for Current year and previous year for all companies

2) List the previous year sales value for that company and week if it exists. (example cmp 1234 is missing week 13, 2013, so show the value of that week in 2012)

I've tried joins but I either get 0 values returned or millions of values returned. I just don't really know where to even start.

I'm very new to SQL and greatly appreciate any help offered. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
SELECT TableA.*, bPrev.sales
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
   ON  TableA.cmp_code = TableB.cmp_code
   And TableA.[Year]   = TableB.[Year]
   And TableA.[Week]   = TableB.[Week]
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB As bPrev
   ON  TableA.cmp_code = bPrev.cmp_code
   And TableA.[Year]   = bPrev.[Year]+1
   And TableA.[Week]   = bPrev.[Week]
WHERE TableB.cmp_code IS NULL
```

Comment: RBarryYoung, Thank you. Where does it define the previous year values?

Comment: @NicholasJDininno Oops, it's supposed to be the second `LEFT` join, but I forgot to make it the previous year.  Hang on ... OK, fixed now.

Comment: This is great! Works like a charm. Thank you. I have one last question and I promise I'll leave you alone. If I add "AND bPrev.othervalue IS NOT NULL" the query takes almost 2 minutes to run. Without that value it takes  1 second. Any idea why?

Comment: @NicholasJDininno That's really a whole separate question of it's own (because performance questions require a lot of other information to anser), but at a guess, just make sure that you are adding that to the bPrev `ON` clause and not to the query's `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it doesn't seem to change the results at all.

Comment: @NicholasJDininno I'd suggest posting this as a separate question then.

Comment: Thanks. I've done as you suggested. Thanks again for your assistance.